# AWK - rounding numbers after matching a word

Tags: bash, awk, numbers, rounding

I would like to print rounded numbers after a word (alter#) match.

input.txt:

```
g11_21           g11_22           g11_23           g11_24          
 g11_25           g11_26           g11_27           g11_28          
 g11_29           g11_30           g11_31           g11_32          
 temper           alter#          
  9.145e-06        8.486e-06          0.5500           0.5500       
    0.5500           0.5500           0.5500           0.5500
```

output.txt:

```
  0       0          1           1       
  1       1          1           1
```

I tried with the following awk code. It can round numbers but I think I did not print them out correctly. Any help is appreciated.

```
awk '/alter#/,EOF {printf("%.0f\n",$0)}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `gawk`

```
awk 'BEGIN   {CONVFMT="%.0f"} 
     f       {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i+0; print}; 
     /alter#/{f=1}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '{
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
  if(!flag){
    if($i == "alter#"){
      flag=1}
};
  if(flag && $i && $i != "alter#"){
    val=1;
    printf ("%0.0f ", $i)}
};
  if(val){
    print ""
};
  val=""
}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

Comment: @JaeyoungPark, as per your sample date, since you want to cover all the field's data so only loop is needed, if your actual data looks different from sample one then kindly do let me know on same.

Comment: I see. Thank you.